# Perl syntax usage, use strict and local

Tags: perl

I have problem with Perl `local` syntax.

The code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

&outer;

sub outer {
    local $lvar = 'local';
    &inner;
}

sub inner {
    print "lvar: $lvar\n";
}
```

If I run the code, it outputs:

```
lvar: local
```

But if the code is modified as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

&outer;

sub outer {
    local $lvar = 'local';
    &inner;
}

sub inner {
    print "lvar: $lvar\n";
}
```

Then, errors occur:

```
Global symbol "$lvar" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 7.
Global symbol "$lvar" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 12.
Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I am confused here.  I want to minimize the scope of `$lvar`, and I also want to use `strict` directive.  But it seems they can not coexist.

Can `use strict;` and `local` coexist?  Or, shall I state `our $lvar`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`local` is almost never what you want. Use `my`, which declares a variable that is visible throughout (the rest of) an enclosing block.

It's unclear exactly what you want to do, but if you need to share a variable between two subroutines and protect it from access elsewhere then you can write something like this. Note that this is a *closure* and the value of `$lvar` is persistent across calls to either subroutine.

Note that you shouldn't call subroutines using the `&subname` syntax. That has been wrong since Perl 5 was introduced in 1994. Use `subname()` instead.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

outer();

{
  my $lvar;

  sub outer {
      $lvar = 'local';
      inner();
  }

  sub inner {
      print "lvar: $lvar\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Borodin. Another question. A lot of people (including you) told me that i should not call subroutine like '&subroutine', i should use 'subroutine()'. But i do not understand why. Can you enlighten me? i use '&subroutine' just want to show that this routine is user-defined.

Comment: @ruanhao: Because `&subroutine` **a)** overrides any prototypes there may be in the subroutine definition, and **b)** passes the current value of `@_` as a parameter list when you would expect it to pass an empty list, so you are forced to use parentheses around any parameters. It is also ugly and, as I said, nearly twenty years out of date. If you want to separate user-defined subroutines from built-in operators then you can precede them with `my_`, but I have never seen a case where it has been done, or has been necessary.

Comment: I regularly work on code that uses `&` to distinguish in-house subs from those provided by others' modules, so you are not alone.  But `&outer;` does invoke the unexpected behaviour Borodin mentions in "b)"; so you should always use parentheses when you use `&`, as in `&outer()`.

Answer (score 7):

Use `my` to declare lexical variables. How about this rewrite?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
outer();

sub outer {
    my $lvar = 'local';
    inner($lvar);
}

sub inner {
    my $lvar = shift;
    print "lvar: $lvar\n";
}
```

Resources:

[Coping with Scoping](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html) (includes discussion of `my` versus `local`).

Another good resource is the book [Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/modern_perl_letter.pdf). Just search for "lexical".

Answer (score 5):

`local` does not declare/create variables — it just creates an auto-restoring backup of an existing variable — so you still have to declare `$lvar`. Since `local` only works with package variables<sup>[1]</sup>, this is one of the rare occasions where one needs to use `our` instead of `my`.

```
outter();
sub outter {
    local our $lvar = 'local';
    inner();
}
sub inner {
    our $lvar;
    print "lvar: $lvar\n";
}
```

You could also declare the variable "globally".

```
our $lvar;
outter();
sub outter {
    local $lvar = 'local';
    inner();
}
sub inner {
    print "lvar: $lvar\n";
}
```

Or just once for the two subs.

```
outter();
{
   our $lvar;
   sub outter {
       local $lvar = 'local';
       inner();
   }
   sub inner {
       print "lvar: $lvar\n";
   }
}
```

But really, `local` is something you should only want to use when you are forced to use package variables. When creating your own variables, you want to use `my` instead.

```
outter();
{
   my $lvar;
   sub outter {
       $lvar = 'local';
       inner();
   }
   sub inner {
       print "lvar: $lvar\n";
   }
}
```

---

1. It also works with hash elements and array elements of both lexical and package variables.

Comment: is there some reference to localizing `lexical` hash elements?

Comment: @mpapec, [Temporary Values via local()](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Temporary-Values-via-local%28%29)

Comment: Doesn't specifically say it can do it to lexical hashes and arrays, but it doesn't say you can't either.

Comment: yes, and `Localization of elements of composite types` is also lacking. did you look at source, or red that somewhere?

Comment: @mpapec, huh? No, I already told you where it's documented. 5th example: `local $hash{key} = "val";` and second paragraph: "Some types of lvalues can be localized as well: hash and array elements and slices, conditionals (provided that their result is always localizable), and symbolic references."